# Drupal 7 render a node chain

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to display, in a single page, the content of nodes referenced to other(e. g. the relations of a navigation graph)
This should not be a simple list of node, but it should follows the order of the relations between nodes. 
How can I do this?
PHP code?
Template?
View?
This should be done in a recursive way?
I'm working with Drupal 7...
Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Michele

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without using custom module, then you should consider using module http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url and http://drupal.org/project/views_attach along with Views. View attach gives you **Node Content** display which you can use to implement the functionality you are looking forward to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggests, but I can't see the D / versione for these modules. So... I'm writing a new D 7 module!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an [Entity Relationship Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)

This is possible in Drupal 6 using the [Node Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) module and it's dependencies.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a port to Drupal 7 yet.

If you didn't need to show the entire relationship graph in one place but could click thru: in Drupal 7 to show nodes related to a given node you can adapt the recipe to show referenced content found here:

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37

Using the following projects:

- [References](http://drupal.org/project/references)
- [Node Reference URL](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) - Port to D7 with latest patch in [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/701670)
- [Eve (the possible successor to Views Attach)](https://github.com/eaton/eve)

Comment: Hi, after a demo with a new custom module I'll try the nodereference url D 7 port. Thanks